# Server boot black screen, how can I log in?

Tags: server

After install Ubuntu server 11.10, My server doesn't show login screen. At first i can see a purple screen after that my screen go to black and cursor not blink

Please tell me how I can go to login screen?

Comment: This is text boot
http://upic.me/i/z0/ubuntu-printscreen2.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to tty1. There you can log in. I don't know if this is a bug or a new feature. But my precise server does the same.